# How to use strategy pattern with additional methods in derived classes

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I'm writing a project in which I'm using strategy, however, my derived classes have other additional functionalities which the base class shouldn't have.

```
class Base {
        public:
            virtual void execute() = 0;
            virtual void print() const noexcept = 0;
            virtual ~Base() {}
        };


class DerivedA : public virtual Base {
        public:
            void execute() override;
            void print() const noexcept override;
            void doSomething();

        private:
            int x;
            double y;
};

class DerivedB final : public Base {
        public:
            void execute() override;
            void print() const noexcept override;
            std::string getZ() const noexcept;

        private:
            std::string z;
        };
```

In main(), I'm trying to use dynamic_cast to be able to use this additional functionality like this:

```
int main() {

    DerivedA da;
    Base* base = &da;
    DerivedA* derivedA = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(base);
    derivedA.doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to run the code I get the following error:

**'DerivedA *' differs in levels of indirection from 'DerivedA'**

My questions are, should I be even using strategy for this, or should I be using another design pattern? And if I should use strategy, how can I solve this error?

**UPDATE**

I'm thinking of switching to decorator, since the DerivedA can be a base class for DerivedB, however, I'm worried about casting, since each class has different class members.

**UPDATE**

Seems like I wrote the casting wrong. However, I wrote it right when posting it here! It works now, but, I agree that there's a better way to implement this.

Comment: derivedA->doSomething()

Comment: That's what I thought also. When I try to do it, I get a warning **expression must have pointer type**

Comment: Concerning your Update: In your current example, `DerivedA` is not a super class of `DerivedB`. If it was `DerivedB` would inherit members from all it's base classes including `DerivedA`.

Comment: It's not because, on the begining, I thought that it would be better to implement strategy. However, I'm reviewing my design, and thinking that I should change it and implement decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is exactly the code you're trying to compile, the solution is easy.  Instead of

```
derivedA.doSomething();
```

you should write

```
derivedA->doSomething();
```

Since derived is a pointer, not a reference or instance.

However, I do have some other serious concerns about considering `dynamic_cast`.  My opinion is that if you use `dynamic_cast` there is probably something wrong in your design.  You have an interface hiding the implementations, yet have code that relies on the implementations and not in the interface.

Some alternatives to consider:

- Try to convert the implementation-specific methods to something that makes sense on the interface.  Maybe you can find some common concept for all the implementations.
- Extract the implementation-specific methods into 'capability' interfaces and provide functionality in the interface to get a 'capability' interface.  E.g. if your base class is `IAnimal`, and some of your animals can swim, make an interface `ISwimmable` and add a method to `IAnimal` that return a pointer to `ISwimmable` (`IAnimal::getSwimmable`).  Animal implementations that can swim, can inherit from `ISwimmable` and implement `getSwimmable` and return a pointer to the `ISwimmable` interface (so actually, return an upcast of itself, which is simply implicitly itself).  Animals that can't swim can return a `nullptr` (which could be the default implementation in `IAnimal` or some `AnimalBase` class inheriting from `IAnimal` if you want to keep the interface a pure interface).

This second approach is also used by Microsoft's COM system, where every COM interface implements the `IUnknown` interface, and where you can call `IUnknown` to get a specific, different interface for some 'capability'.

Comment: The capability interface seems like a great idea for this case. However, each derived class has different class members and a different number of them. I'm not sure how to solve that without casting?

Comment: Oh right, I can just use a non pure interface. This is a great advice! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a  common problem in software, and one that crops up a lot in various design patterns. You want to use `DerivedA` and `DerivedB` polymporphically, so they have to share a common interface. That's fine. However `DerivedA` has a useful  method `doSomething` you want to use as well. Your options are either:

1. Don't use the `doSomething` method, which keeps your code nice and clean;
2. Do a runtime typecheck and cast so you can access `doSomething`, but then your code unavoidably looks a bit hacky;
3. Implement `doSomething` in `Base` to do nothing, then your code looks nice, but when you call `doSomething` on a `Base` reference, it will do nothing if the receiving object in actually of class `DerivedB`.

Decorator won't really help here. Decorator is good for augmenting existing methods. You can't use it (in a statically typed language) to add new methods, as I learned the hard way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Code below iw working file for me, with g++ and compilation:
g++ main.cc -o main -std=c++14

```
#include <string>

class Base {
        public:
            virtual void execute() = 0;
            virtual void print() const noexcept = 0;
            virtual ~Base() {}
        };


class DerivedA : public virtual Base {
        public:
            void execute() override {}
            void print() const noexcept override {}
            void doSomething(){}

        private:
            int x;
            double y;
};

class DerivedB final : public Base {
        public:
            void execute() override {}
            void print() const noexcept override {}
            std::string getZ() const noexcept {}

        private:
            std::string z;
        };
int main() {

    DerivedA da;
    Base* base = &da;
    DerivedA* derivedA = dynamic_cast<DerivedA*>(base);
    derivedA->doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```